# Text turned into squares

Tags: fonts, errors, formatting, tex-general

I finished a previous LaTeX session with correct working file. When I opened it in the next time, all letters turned into squares. There is no .bac file in the directory. Is it possible to turn back to the correct file? How? I'm lost

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which TeX distribution to you use? What is a "correct working file" -- a tex file, a pdf file, or something else? "When I opened *it* the next time" -- which file are we talking about? Incidentally, are the squares (rectangles, maybe?) solid or hollow? Did you try to reboot your system and check if the problem persists?

Comment: I'm working with MikTeX in TeXstudio under Windows 10. Under correct working file I mean a .tex file that has no errors and whose compilation produces .dvi. Reopening this .tex file leads to hollow squares on the screen. Other .tex files are without any changes. Reboot did not help.

Comment: Does rebooting the system and/or re-installing TeXstudio bring any relief?

Comment: Reboot did not help. Meanwhile I did not try re-installing

Comment: Could it be that TeXstudio is using a font which doesn't include any of the glyphs in the alphabet(s) you're using?

Comment: I don't think so, because it worked. The file was shown properly both in TeXstudio and in dvi viewer after compilation.

Comment: So if you open the file in another text editor, like notepad, it doesn't show the rectangles? Or is it only the dvi which shows them?

Comment: Notepad does not open it. The rectangles replaced the text also in .tex file itself

Comment: Could it be that the dvi file was accidentally copied onto (and thus overwrote) the tex file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be about having trashed the file itself (and if not it's not clear _what_ has actually happened).

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late but I found your question only after I ran into the same problem. Do you sync your documents to google drive? If yes, then you might be in luck. Go to your drive folder in the browser, right click the file you want to restore, click 'manage versions' and select the file you want to fall back to. Google keeps older versions for only 30 days, you should still try though. If you use a different syncing facility it might have a similar versioning facility, I am not sure though.

Alternatively, can you still open a working pdf file? If yes, then convert it to a word document, paste everything to a tex file, and 'replace all' the text/math that is not translated properly. Knowledge of regular expressions might be helpful here. I have not tried this personally but I was gonna do it if above method didn't work.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: The same goes for Dropbox.